# Can GitHub review comments transition to next commit?

Tags: github, pull-request

Say, I committed some code, created a pull request, then someone requested changes.
If I go to diff, I can see those comments. However if I make changes and commit, those comments won't show up. Is there a way to keep them there? Sort of like Atlassian's Crucible does.
Cause it would be a lot easier to see what was actually changed here and for what reason

Comment: The same thing seems to happen with Bitbucket, and yes, it's annoying and sometimes would be nice to retain those comments +1